# javascript page redirection without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache, browser-history

I have a situation where you scroll down a page to a certain button that clicked will lead to a new page (in the same window).

If inside the new page I implement another button that via JS returns to the starting page using history.back() it has the benefit that the user lands on the exact (scrolled down) point where he clicked the first button.

New situation:
I’d love to keep this benefit, but I can’t use history.back() instead I have to use the src of the original page. Doing so by f.e. using window.location.href = "my_starting_url"; it goes back to the original page but at the top of the page. Why? Is there a simple method to achieve the same behavior as history.back() i.e. reopening the page at the same (cached) point?

Did I explain myself sufficiently?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have a search for 'HTML bookmarks'

Comment: The only system I can think of to perform what you want is way too complex for the small benefit it brings. If you can be more specific to where you want to scroll (it not being "the previous scroll position of the user), anchors are probably the solution.

Comment: First of all thanks for your fast replies! The bookmark thing seems the right for my situation at first glance! I will experiment with that first.

Comment: @Bartdude: yeah, it must be previous scroll position.

Comment: @Bartdude: My first idea was to define a global variable that will count the clicks made from the new page and then use this variable to implement it somehow with history.back(-myVariable). But to make things even more complicated there is php in action creating the pages. So I would have to alter a global variable from there… too much for me I am afraid

Comment: you can store the scrollTop in sessionStorage onunload(), and set it onload

Comment: Thanks Rory! The bookmarks just went fine for me! Excellent and very simple to manage!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it the best option would be the History API ( http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html ): This will allow you to fetch a new page and store the scroll position of the current one, once the user clicks on "back" you can load the previous page and set the scroll position exactly where it was.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that the most accurate solution would go in this direction. Sadly I always had a very hard time understanding this history.push stuff. I will yet try again to understand it if the bookmark solution from comment above is not practicable.